# How to Connect printer to macbook pro

Tags: printing

I have a printer HP deskjet f4210 connected to a windows 7 system, I am trying to connect my macbook pro os 10.7.4 to it, however I get the message authentication required. I tried entering guest/guest as I found this tip from another forum, and it connected. However it goes through the print process and nothing is printed. There are no errors, it shows the progress bar and then the job is removed from the queue as if its printed.

What is the fix?

Comment: Tried typing your windows pc name and password on authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Have you done a software update? As HP updates their drivers to suit different versions of OSX different updates are pushed through to users. [Read more on hp's website.](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02911238&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=3746674)

You could also try [resetting the printer system.](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01371980&tmp_track_link=ot_recdoc/c01846935/en_us/c01371980/loc:2&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&man_lang=de&product=3746674#N308)